# Weird address parameter when switching between full and mobile versions

Tags: support, mobile-web, full-site

Whenever I switch between full and mobile versions of the site (via links in the footer) I see weird unique parameter in browser's address line:

> [image: param]

What's this?

Comment: It is a cache breaker

Comment: I think it is needed to prevent the browser to serve you the main page from its cache where it really need to be a new fetch from the server to give you the mobile html, css and javascript. Otherwise you might end-up with an unhealthy mix of mobile and full-site versions of those files.

Comment: @rene are there any other ways to switch between sites without spoiling address line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typical of the way jQuery handles Ajax calls, which

> works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters.

([source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

If you dig a bit through the JavaScript of the Stack Exchange site, you'll see that there are some Ajax calls involved in switching between the full and the mobile site.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent this ugly additive?

Comment: @alexolut no. My browser (Safari) shows nothing but the host (meta.stackexchange.com) anyway.

Comment: if you make a tap on the address line you will see it in Safari too.

Comment: @Glorfindel In case you weren’t aware, that’s an option in Safari Preferences > Advanced.